# Adding a 3D point using Epilog

Tags: graphics3d

I am trying to add a point using the Epilog option with ContourPlot3D.

```
ContourPlot3D[{x == 0, y == 0, z == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 
  3}, {z, -3, 3},
 Mesh -> None,
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
 ContourStyle -> {Opacity[0.8]},
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{1, -2, 2}]}]
```

But it doesn't work. Suggestions?

Comment: `Epilog` is really only useful for appending two-dimensional primitives to either `Graphics[]` or `Graphics3D[]`. Use `Show[]` instead: `Show[ContourPlot3D[(* stuff *)], Graphics3D[(* stuff *)]]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Not entirely true. The Epilog doc page shows a couple of arguably useful applications in amending 3D graphics.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries. Yes, but the graphics primitives in the list given to the `Epilog` option must all be 2D.

Comment: @m_goldberg I know that, but was responding to guesswho's remark that Epilog is useless in cases other than for appending to 2D graphics. It's not. Browse through the examples.

Comment: @Sjoerd, prolly didn't express myself clearly; I meant it in the sense of m_goldberg's reading. Yes, you can annotate 3D graphics with it, but it's not useful for appending three-dimensional primitives.