# How to plot points using ParametricPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I have the following Mathematica code:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{0 + 0*t, 10 - 1*t, 9 - 1*t}, {7 - t, 7 - t, 
6 - t}, {0, 0, -1}}, {t, 12, -20}]
```

The last "parametric curve" $(0, 0, -1)$ is a point I want to plot as a visible ball or disc or whatever. At the moment I can't see it.

How can I plot visible points in addition to parametric curves? I don't actually think I can state the 3D point and expect it to appear as I currently have it...

Currently the code displays the following:

[image: Mathematica output]

**UPDATE**

A temporary fix for now is the following code:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{0 + 0*t, 10 - 1*t, 9 - 1*t}, {7 - t, 7 - t, 
6 - t}, {0 + Sin[t], 0 + Cos[t], -1}}, {t, 12, -20}]
```

It would be nice to plot a ball though...

[image: Mathematica output]

Comment: Related: [(52259)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52259/121), [(84047)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84047/121).  Possible duplicate: [(41439)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41439/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{{0 + 0*t, 10 - 1*t, 9 - 1*t}, {7 - t, 7 - t, 6 - t}}, {t, 12, -20}],
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.04], Red, Point[{0, 0, -1}]}]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Also: `Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{0, 0, -1}]}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I like that one :-)